Nginx server running in docker container not displaying static files
Here is my docker file I have a image for composer and php from here I install node.js and all requirements
FROM composer:2.7.7
FROM php:8.3.3-fpm-alpine3.19

# Install required packages
RUN apk add --no-cache nodejs npm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html

COPY --from=0 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
# Ensure permissions are set correctly
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/public/build/assets
USER www-data

#composer run commands
RUN composer update
RUN composer install

#npm run commands
RUN npm install vite
RUN npm run build
USER root

But once I get to my compose.yml file I don't know if should be mounting a volume for my static files or not I figured that it would be done in the ngnix config file
  version: '3.8'

services:
    rental-project:
        image: rental-project:0.14.0
        container_name: rental-project
        env_file:
            - .env
        networks:
            - rentalProject-api-network

    web-server:
        image: nginx:1.24.0-alpine-slim
        container_name: web-server
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./laravel.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        networks:
            - rentalProject-api-network

    mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        container_name: mysql_container
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_DATABASE: rentalProject
            MYSQL_USER: rentalProject
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
        volumes:
            - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./dumps:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        networks:
            - rentalProject-api-network

    volumes:
        mysql_data:
    
    
    networks:
        rentalProject-api-network:

As previously stated I figured that here is where I would configure my nginx server to serve static files but I could be wrong i looked at many topics but it led to more confusion.
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /assets {
        alias /var/www/html/public/build/assests;
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;
        autoindex_localtime on;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;


    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass rental-project:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

When I check the inspector I get the following errors, am I missing an extra step somewhere?


Is /homeProperty.js really supposed to work? You didn't tell us where that file is on disk, but I guess it should be /assets/homeProperty.js?  Same for the stuff in /build/assets/ - your nginx config sets up an alias for that dir, why aren't you using it?  If you don't need it, delete it from the config to keep things simple.

And you have a typo in that alias, as an answer here already correctly pointed out.

Your Nginx config says to look for all files, except PHP files, inside the Nginx container. And they aren't there. Where are your .js and .css files located?

You misspelled assets as assests here:
    location /assets {
        alias /var/www/html/public/build/assests;
...

change it to :
    location /assets {
        alias /var/www/html/public/build/assets;

Also you had better add mime types
include mime.types;

